# "Cannot use import statement outside a module" error when deploying to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I'm fairly new to both development and Heroku but I am working through trying to deploy a react app. I can run the app perfectly fine when I run it locally, however I keep running into issues when I try to deploy to Heroku. It appears to build successfully, however I keep ending up with an application error and when I check the heroku logs I get the following:

[heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeD8w.png)

When I searched for this syntax error it seems to be pretty popular and it looks like it might have something to do with my index.js file being buried in client -> src -> index.js (I specify this location in my Procfile). What I don't understand though is why this import error doesn't give me any trouble locally, only when I try to push to Heroku.

Edit:

Additional error is logged here. [No Demon Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gpos.png)

Comment: you need to serve the build with command  serve -s build instead of node with index.js

Comment: It will be better if you can share some code snippets.

Comment: Hi Guys- I was fortunate enough to be able to make some progress I think... I had a couple errors which contributed to my original post but after specifying the path and location of in index.js file using `app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'src', 'index.js'));
});` that seemed to resolve it. That being said however, I am no getting a separate issue. Please see additional image attached to original post. I am using the npm run dev command in the Procfile that I use locally to launch the app however I think it is contributing to the nodemon error.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when trying to deploy my first react app to heroku

I found a super simple solution that makes deploying to heroku painless.

Here are the steps I followed to do this:

```
create-react-app $APP_NAME
cd $APP_NAME
git init
heroku create $APP_NAME --buildpack https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildkit.git
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push heroku master
```

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDiQrgeGTuU&t=135s][1] Here is a link to the youtube video I followed.

As far as I can tell the buildpack was the major key here as it did most of the heavy lifting in terms of preparing the app for launch.

Answer (score -2):

I tried this, but got the following error

-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack

-----> Using buildpack: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildkit.git

!     error fetching custom buildpack https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildkit.git

!     Push failed

Comment: Please go over the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer before posting an answer. What you have here is not an answer.